# Kill process with command line

Tags: windows, command-line, zonealarm

I have a few programs I would like to shutdown before I start gaming.

I managed to make a batch file for it, but 1 program doesn't isn't terminated.

The first two processes do shutdown, but for some reason Zonealarm doesn't.
I also disabled the "Protect client" option in Zonealarm, but still, the process keeps on running.

```
TASKKILL /F /IM "Msseces.exe"
TASKKILL /F /IM "MsMpEng.exe"
TASKKILL /F /IM "zlclient.exe"  < this one doesn't shutdown
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process is protected by a driver/kernel hook. There's no easy way to kill the ZoneAlarm main process... And you shouldn't want to kill it either...

Comment: Well, I dont have any stranges purposes with it, but for gaming it's better. I'm also a bit lazy and find something very interesting if a proces can't be killed normally. Man over machine :)

Comment: @Chris don't get me wrong, I'm sure there is a way to kill it using 3rd party software but there's no standard batch like way as you are trying now.

Comment: thank you all. It's not killable on a normal way

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, I have had similar results as you.  I've found that `taskkill` doesn't always work.  You might have better luck with [Sysinternal's pskill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx).  Sysinternals is free and a lot of people swear by it.